# Create PDF with Trim marks using PDFLaTeX

Tags: pdftex, pdf-with-trim

My code follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\paperheight}{9truein}%
\setlength{\paperwidth}{8truein}%

\makeatletter
\setlength\oddsidemargin{5pc}
\addtolength\oddsidemargin{-1in}    
\setlength\@tempdima{\paperwidth}
\addtolength\@tempdima{-\textwidth}
\addtolength\@tempdima{-5pc}
\setlength\evensidemargin{\@tempdima}
\addtolength\evensidemargin{-1in}
\makeatother
\usepackage[a4,cam,center,info]{crop}
\setlength\textwidth{30pc}
\setlength\textheight{40pc}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

`Trim` marks and got cut in the output PDF file, refer the below image for your reference:

[image]

But I need the `PDF` output with `Trim` marks and the `Trim` marks should not be cut, e.g.,

[image]

Please suggest the possibilities...

Comment: You should also use the `geometry` package to set up your margins rather than messing around with `\textwidth` and `\textheight` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the "paper" that you ask `crop` to put your document on (A4) doesn't leave enough space for your desired paper size plus the marks. So just choose another paper size as option for `crop`.

If none of the standard sizes of the package is convenient for you, you can also choose a custom one, e.g. `[width=10truein,height=11truein]`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\paperheight}{9truein}%
\setlength{\paperwidth}{8truein}%

\makeatletter
\setlength\oddsidemargin{5pc}
\addtolength\oddsidemargin{-1in}    
\setlength\@tempdima{\paperwidth}
\addtolength\@tempdima{-\textwidth}
\addtolength\@tempdima{-5pc}
\setlength\evensidemargin{\@tempdima}
\addtolength\evensidemargin{-1in}
\makeatother

\usepackage[width=10truein,height=11truein,cam,center,info]{crop}

\setlength\textwidth{30pc}
\setlength\textheight{40pc}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```